# Explode or pivot spark scala dataframe horizontally to create a big flat dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I have a dataframe with following schema:

```
UserID | StartDate | endDate | orderId | OrderCost| OrderItems| OrderLocation| Rank
```

Where `Rank` is 1 to 10.
I need to transpose this dataframe on rank and create dataframe in the below format:

```
UserID| StartDate_1 | endDate_1 | orderId_1 | OrderCost_1| OrderItems_1| OrderLocation_1|start_2 |endDate_2| orderId_2 | OrderCost_2| OrderItems_2| OrderLocation_2 |............| startDate_N|endDate_N | orderId_N | OrderCost_N| OrderItems_N| OrderLocation_N
```

If a user has only two records with rank 3 and 10 then the requirement is populate columns with suffix `_3` and `_10` the rest of the cell values for the user will be null.

I have tried 2 brute force approaches

1. Filter the DF for a rank, and rename the columns with suffix and do self join back to DF.
2. Grouped by UserID, collect as list and pass it to map function where I populate a array based on rank and then return the seq of string. Create the DF by passing the required schema

Both seemed to be working (Unsure if its the right approach
)but they are not generic that i can re use for different usecase i have

Comment: Hi, @user1835010, pls add your efforts too, what have you tried ?

Comment: @syadav I have tried out couple of brute for approach but they are tedious and are specifc to the above use case

Answer (score 0):

In this example I used https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/sampledata/_data/auto-mpg.csv

Spark by default puts the rank in front, so the column names are "reversed" from what you specified, but this is done in only a few steps. The key is that `exprs` should be dynamically created, and that `agg` requires this to be split into a head and tail (which is why there is `.agg(exprs(0), exprs.slice(1, exprs.length)` below)

```
scala> df2.columns

res39: Array[String] = Array(mpg, cyl, displ, hp, weight, accel, yr, origin, name, Rank)

// note here, you would use columns.slice with the indices for
// the columns you need, i.e. (1, 7)
val exprs = for (col <- df2.columns.slice(0, 8)) yield expr(s"first(${col}) as ${col}")

exprs: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(first(mpg, false) AS `mpg`, first(cyl, false) AS `cyl`, first(displ, false) AS `displ`, first(hp, false) AS `hp`, first(weight, false) AS `weight`, first(accel, false) AS `accel`, first(yr, false) AS `yr`, first(origin, false) AS `origin`)

scala> val resultDF = df2.groupBy("name").pivot("Rank").agg(exprs(0), exprs.slice(1, exprs.length):_*)

scala> resultDF.columns
res40: Array[String] = Array(name, 1_mpg, 1_cyl, 1_displ, 1_hp, 1_weight, 1_accel, 1_yr, 1_origin, 2_mpg, 2_cyl, 2_displ, 2_hp, 2_weight, 2_accel, 2_yr, 2_origin, 3_mpg, 3_cyl, 3_displ, 3_hp, 3_weight, 3_accel, 3_yr, 3_origin, 4_mpg, 4_cyl, 4_displ, 4_hp, 4_weight, 4_accel, 4_yr, 4_origin, 5_mpg, 5_cyl, 5_displ, 5_hp, 5_weight, 5_accel, 5_yr, 5_origin, 6_mpg, 6_cyl, 6_displ, 6_hp, 6_weight, 6_accel, 6_yr, 6_origin, 7_mpg, 7_cyl, 7_displ, 7_hp, 7_weight, 7_accel, 7_yr, 7_origin, 8_mpg, 8_cyl, 8_displ, 8_hp, 8_weight, 8_accel, 8_yr, 8_origin, 9_mpg, 9_cyl, 9_displ, 9_hp, 9_weight, 9_accel, 9_yr, 9_origin, 10_mpg, 10_cyl, 10_displ, 10_hp, 10_weight, 10_accel, 10_yr, 10_origin)
```